# How can I open a 360 Youtube Video in the YoutubeVR app from WebVR/A-Frame

Tags: android, youtube, webvr, gear-vr

Since it is not currently possible to embed 360 youtube videos in WebVR/WebXR/A-Frame, I would like it so that when a user clicks a thumbnail, in Samsung Internet on the Gear VR for example, the YouTube 360 video will open in the Youtube VR app 
(provided it's installed on the user's device)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work but getting it to work correctly while you're inside a webvr app might be another issue.

```
<a href="intent://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HI7mTIxNotQ#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.google.android.apps.youtube.vr;end">test</a>
```